# Searching elements in Haskell

Tags: haskell, search

I want an algorithm to find the next position of the first 20 elements of the list.

> I want 20 but using 3 as an example:
>
> Input `x=[1,2,3,0,0,4,4,1,2,3,0,0]`, then return `7` since the next `1,2,3` started at position `7`.
>
> Input `x=[1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3]`, then return `4` since the the next `1,2,3` started at position `4`.
>
> Input `x=[2,1,2,1,2]`, then return `2` since the next `2,1,2` started at position `2`.
>
> If no matching is found, return `-1`.

I tried the simplest one by just checking every position one by one:

```
repeat x = repeat' x 0 x
  where repeat' x position originlist 
        | length x <=20         = -1
        | take 20 (tail x) == y = position+1
        | otherwise             = repeat' (tail x) (position+1) originlist
         where y = take 20 originalist
```

But this is too slow, I need to deal with list of length up to 2*10^6. Since the search tool in browsers like Chrome or Safari can matching it in the blink of an eye, there must be an better algorithm(Or better code in Haskell rather than what I typed).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like Knuth-Morris-Patterson algorithm; does the *sublist* always starts at the beginning? Given for your example with `3`; the array is `[1,2,3,4,2,3,4]`; should this return `4`?

Comment: @CommuSoft Yes it always starts at the beginning. It should return `-1` since there is no `1,2,3` except the first.

Comment: The question is still very confusing. You have plenty of examples, but the actual description of what you want remains unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious problem is

```
| length x <=20         = -1
```

This makes your code `O(m*n^2)`, where `m` is the length of the short list and `n` is the length of the long one. The trouble is that the program has to walk the entire length of the list to calculate its length, even though you only care about the first twenty elements. It's possible to speed up that test, or to integrate it into the equality check, but since you expect the lists to be long, you should see a dramatic improvement by just skipping it altogether:

```
repeat p = repeat' p 0 p
 where
  repeat' [] = -1
  repeat' (x : xs) position originlist
    | take 20 xs == y = position+1
    | otherwise       = repeat' xs (position+1) originlist
     where y = take 20 originalist
```

Note that I've removed the calls to `tail`, which will throw an exception if called with an empty list, and replaced it with a pattern match on the front if the list.

This is still rather hard to read/understand, but it's the best I could do with just a fragment of the original code and without understanding exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: You should include the reason why this line is slow.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Z-algorithm](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2011/cmsc858s/Lec02-zalg.pdf) you may solve this problem very efficiently. By definition:

> `Z(S, i)`: The length of *longest* substring of `S` *starting* at index `i` which is also a *prefix* of `S`.

For example, for string `abcababca` we have:

```
index  | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
-------|------------------
string | a b c a b a b c a
z.func | 8 0 0 2 0 3 0 0 1
```

z-function [can be efficiently calculated in O(n)](https://e-maxx-eng.github.io/string/z-function.html), and once you have this function your problem reduces to finding the first index which has z-value exceeding the threshold;

For example your first list has z-function:

```
\> toList.zfunc.fromList $ [1,2,3,0,0,4,4,1,2,3,0,0]
[12,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0]
```

and (skipping the very first index), you get the first value larger than 3 at index 7!

Below is a possible implementation of z-algorithm in Haskell:

```
import Data.List (mapAccumL)
import Data.Vector (Vector, toList, fromList, fromListN, (!))
import qualified Data.Vector as V

zfunc :: Eq a => Vector a -> Vector Int
zfunc a = out
    where
    n = V.length a :: Int
    out = fromListN n (n:rest) :: Vector Int
    rest = snd . mapAccumL loop (0, 0) $ [1..n - 1] :: [Int]

    loop :: (Int, Int) -> Int -> ((Int, Int), Int)
    loop (l, r) i
        | r < i + 1 = ((i, r'), r' - i)
        | i + out ! (i - l) < r = ((l, r), out ! (i - l))
        | otherwise = ((i, r''), r'' - i)
        where
        next = head . dropWhile (\j -> j < n && a ! j == a ! (j - i))
        [r', r''] = map next [[i..], [r..]] :: [Int]
```

Comment: There's an implementation of the Z algorithm on Hackage here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/zalgo